# Implementing Interface and trying it out with Array and List - java

Tags: java, arrays, list, interface

I have to implement an interface and try it out in two different classes one with Array and one with List. In these classes we have to add different methods as seen in the interface ->

```
public interface IStatistics {
    public void addSample(String name, GregorianCalendar date, double value);
    public double getMeanTemperature(int month);  
    public double getMedianTemperature(int month);
    public double getVariance(int month);
    public double getStandardDeviation(int month);
    public void printSamples(int month);

}
```

I've already done most of it but it should only use the values from a specific month which doesn't work in both methods. In this exercise we get a certain value every day for one year(name, date, temperature). I don't know how to get it to only use the values from one month(which doesn't work in both classes) In the List I already tried it out but it doesn't work at all.

```
    @Override
    public double getMeanTemperature(int month) {
        MeasurementValue m = this.head;
        double result = 0;
        while(m.date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)==month){
            while(m!=null){
                result = result + m.temp;
                m=m.getNext();
            }
            result = result/this.num;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And in the class with Array I don't even know how to start.

```
    @Override
    public double getMeanTemperature(int month) {
         double sum = 0.0;
        for(double a : values)
            sum += a;
        return sum/numValues;
    }
```

Also it doesn't print out the dates correctly. Maybe anyone knows a solution for that.

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import kwm.statistics.IStatistics;
import kwm.statistics.MeasurementArray;
import kwm.statistics.MeasurementList;

public class TestStatistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2017,05,12);
        GregorianCalendar date1 = new GregorianCalendar(2017,05,02);
        GregorianCalendar date2 = new GregorianCalendar(2017,05,22);
        GregorianCalendar date3 = new GregorianCalendar(2017,06,06);
        GregorianCalendar date4 = new GregorianCalendar(2017,05,18);

//      ***TESTLIST***
        IStatistics statistics1 = new MeasurementList();
        statistics1.addSample("Lisa", date, 12);
        statistics1.addSample("Lisa", date1, 17);
        statistics1.addSample("Lisa", date2, 14);
        statistics1.printSamples(5);

//      ***TESTARRAY***
        IStatistics statistics2 = new MeasurementArray();

        statistics2.addSample("Lisa", date, 12);
        statistics2.addSample("Lisa", date1, 5);
        statistics2.addSample("Lisa", date2, 40);
        statistics2.addSample("Lisa", date3, 31);
        statistics2.addSample("Lisa", date4, 23);
        statistics2.printSamples(5);

    }

}
```

That's the code for the output in MeasurementValue

```
public void output(){
    GregorianCalendar date = this.date;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    System.out.print(sdf.format(date.getTime()));
}
```

And the code for the output in MeasurementList.

```
public void printSamples(int month) {

        MeasurementValue m = this.head;
//      while(m.date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)==month){
            while(m != null){
                if(month>=0 && 11>=month){
                    System.out.println("Name: "+m.getName());
                    System.out.println("Value: "+m.getTemp());
                    System.out.print("Date: ");m.output();
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    System.out.print("*****************\n\n");
                    m = m.getNext();
                }
            }
//      }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Too much code. Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With an emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: Nobody here is going to read a wall of code.

Comment: or debug it for that matter

Comment: Side note: the prefix `I` for interface names is generally nonconformant with the Java naming conventions and arguably serves no useful purpose. Identifiers should reveal role and purpose, not implementation.

Comment: Calendar MONTH values are 0-based. So 5 is actually june. That may explain why you believe the dates are not printed correctly.

Comment: No it acutally prints out -> Date: 31.12.0002

Comment: Then you should provide the code of MeasurementValue.output() which formats the dates.

Comment: @BladeCoder just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

For the linked list version, try something like this:

```
@Override
public double getMeanTemperature(int month) {
    double total = 0d;
    int num = 0;
    for (MeasurementValue m = this.head; m != null; m = m.getNext()) {
        if (m.date.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
            total += m.temp;
            num++;
        }
    }
    if (num == 0) {
       // Avoid division by zero
       return 0d;
    }
    return total / (double) num;
}
```

Same principle for the array but you iterate differently (and you need to store the months as well).